# $f:[a,b]\to[c,d]$ is absolutely continuous and bijective. Is $f^{-1}$ of bounded variation? Does $m(E) = 0$ imply $m(f(E))=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation, absolute-continuity

Suppose we have a function $f:[a,b]\to[c,d]$ that is absolutely continuous and bijective, where $f^{-1}:[c,d]\to [a,b]$ is the inverse. I need to determine:

1. if $f^{-1}\in BV[c,d]$, and
2. if it is true that $m(f(E)) = 0$ when $E\subseteq [a,b]$ with $m(E) = 0$.

Here $m$ denotes the Lebesgue measure.

I am pretty stuck on how to approach this problem. I know the definition of absolutely continuous, as well as the equivalent statements about differentiability and integration. I also know that absolutely continuous implies being of bounded variation, and that being of bounded variation is true iff the function is the difference of two bounded increasing functions.

I have all of these facts, but I'm not sure how to use them to figure out this problem. Any suggestions on how to start would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is continuous and one to one the it is monotonic. Hence $f^{-1}$ is also monotonic.  Monotonic functions are of BV. This answers 1) (absolute continuity is not required here!). The fact that absolutely continuous functions map sets of measure 0 to sets of measure 0 is standard. This can be found in Rudin's RCA and also on MSE